# Spring XML - ignore $ in url which is writen in xml , without using propeties file

Tags: spring, spring-bean

I have a spring bean which contain list of strings. Every string represent a url which in runtime is resolved using ognal

For example:

```
www.google.co.il/?name%3d${name}&amp;lastname%3d${lastname}
```

Which is resolved in run time .
How can I ignore spring from looking for this ${} in environment?
For now it takes the properties from environment varibles (I would like it to remain that way and just in this list to ignore placeholders)

E.g.:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MapFactoryBean"
        id="propertiesHolder">
        <property name="targetMapClass">
            <value>java.util.HashMap</value>
        </property>
        <property name="sourceMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="dateformat" value="dd/MM HH:mm" />
                <entry key="timePickerFormat" value="HH:mm aa" />
                <entry key="timePickerFormat" value="dd/MM HH:mm:ss" />

                    <entry key="AurlTemplate" ><value>
 http://server/domain/main.aspx?pagetype=entityrecord&amp;id=\${id}
                </value>
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**NOTICE**
I tried using **    !  [CDATA[]] ** with no succsses ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
http://server/domain/main.aspx?pagetype=entityrecord&amp;id=#{'$'}{id}
```

This should be escape the dollar sign. The `${...}` are special character for PropertyPlaceHolder and have to been escaped for your issue.